# Spotify Create Playlist API php

Tags: php, javascript, spotify

Can Anyone help me to create the Spotify create playlist PHP Library or JavaScript Method ? i have googled many keywords no one posted to create the playlist for the create new one.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to create a playlist but you can trigger a list of songs to launch in the desktop player by using this format in a link:

`spotify:trackset:PlaylistName:49MsPNQCOmxvIYi9AdoPzY,6fUlrsHaz4QfCNF31rk2dU,5KiTsR2h8jnzkvTeucxoAn,6kidUwWb8tB9ktfy7U76iX,6mlUEdb90RqwUisnp65lG7,6KOEK6SeCEZOQkLj5M1PxH,3psrcZoGRaWh6FMGael1NX,3EHLii6bnZxJxsCfLlIb83,0xJtHBdhpdLuClaSQYddI4,6fsdOFwa9lTG7WKL9sEWRU`

It does not take you to a nice spotify html page first though, just directly to the player.

**UPDATE**

As of today there is an api for creating playlists: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/create-playlist/

Answer (score 1):

Spotify has [recently released an API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/create-playlist/) to accomplish this.

> ### Create a Playlist
>
> Create a playlist for a Spotify user. (The playlist will be empty until you add tracks.)
>
> **Endpoint**
>   `POST https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists`
>   Request Parameters
>   Path parameter Value
>   user_id: The user's Spotify user ID.
>
> ### Example Request
>
> `curl -X POST "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/thelinmichael/playlists" -H "Authorization: Bearer {your access token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"name\":\"A New Playlist\", \"public\":false}"`

Explanation of the other parameters and options are available through the link.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. I've taken the liberty of editing your post with a few relevant bits of code. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

There's no web API for creating playlists. If you really want to do this, you'll need to use libSpotify and a wrapper for it (searching for libSpotify php wrapper will get what you need).